# How to output my data into a new csv file each time I start my C++ program?

Tags: c++, csv

Im a about to develop a program that will prompt user to input numbers and the program will make several calculation and will store the output datas into a csv file.

My question is :

How can I copy and store the data into a new .csv file instead of the existing one each and every time after:

1) I quit and restart the program 
2) When the program suddenly terminates while running(example:My computer suddenly turns off while im running the program due to external errors)?

P.S:Please solve or explain to me with sample codes instead of just words cz im new to c++.

Thanks in advance :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include<string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    float a,b,c;
    ifstream indata;
    ofstream outdata;
    outdata.open("Out.csv", ios::app);//opens the csv file
    outdata << "Num1,Num2,Answer" << endl;//'prompt user for numbers

    while (!(a ==-100))//calculate the product of the numbers
   {    
    cout<<"Enter Num1:";
    cin>>a;
    if(a==-100)break;
    cout<<"Enter Num2:";
    cin>>b;
    c=a*b;
    outdata<<a<<","<<b<<","<<c<< endl;
   }    

    indata.open("out.csv");//stores data into the csv file
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Change `int main()` to `int main(int argc, char* argv[])` and take the filename from the program arguments.

Comment: ... or prompt the user to input the filename also ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <time.h>

time_t now;
time(&now);
char outputFileName[128];
sprintf(outputFileName,"%ld_my_data.csv",now);
```

Comment: Using your previous code,is this the correct way to out data ?

outdata.open("%ld_my_data.csv", ios::app);

Comment: no, the wildcards can be used just for printf C functions, use outdata.open(outputFileName,...) , if you don't want to use C functions you need to construct the filename with a c++ stream , something like out << now << "_my_data.csv"

Answer (score 1):

1) Assemble the filename from the current date and time.

2) If the hardware suddenly stops working or the process is forcibly terminated with kill -9 or Task manager, you get no notification and so you cannot reliably achieve what you seem to want.

'Please solve or explain to me with sample codes instead of just words cz im new to c++'. Get better by writing code and getting it to work:)